# Keep Apache2 configuration and MySQL data in Vagrant package

Tags: vagrant, package, vagrantfile, migrate, vagrant-windows

I currently have a Vagrant box running on Windows 10 and Virtual Box. I have multiple sites enabled in Apache 2 and Mysql databases within the box. While I keep reding that "vagrant package" will compress the whole box except Shared Folders, I can't find a way to retreive the virtual host configuration and MySQL data on another PC.

I want to copy the whole vagrant environnement to another PC.

Maybe I have a misconception about "vagrant package" command

*Steps completed :*

**(ON ORIGINAL WIN10 PC)**

- 1) `vagrant halt`
- 2) `vagrant package --output package-20131222.box`
- 3) zip c:\vagrant (*containing Vagrantfile and /www/ folder*) to vagrant.zip
- 4) Move package-20131222.box and vagrant.zip to new PC

**(ON NEW WIN10 PC)**

- 1) Extract vagrant.zip to c:\vagrant
- 2) Move package-20131222.box and `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 package-20131222.box`
- 3) `vagrant up`

When I SSH to the box, I cannot find my config files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled neither can I see phpMyAdmin or my MySQL databases.

Where did I go wrong ?

Thankss !

Answer (score 1):

`ubuntu/trusty64` is an existing box you should assign your new box a unique name and make sure to use this name in your new Vagrantfile.

The following steps on the new windows machine will work

1. copy package-20131222.box and run `vagrant box add mynewbox package-20131222.box`
2. copy only your Vagrantfile from the old box and change the `config.vm.box = "mynewbox"` (copy any other folder that you need to share with the VM)
3. `vagrant up`

The new VM created will contain all content from the previous VM running on the old windows

Comment: Thanks. Whatever name I used, the Apache config files nor MySQL database can be found within the box...

Comment: you need to use this new name in your vagrantfile, if you let the name that comes from the old windows machine, it will create a new VM from the same initial box